How do I set a background image in .Net Maui?

Guys please tell me how in .Net MAui I can set a background image that will be displayed on all pages and most importantly including the top bar with the time charge on the smartphone?

Welcome to SO. Please read how to ask and familiarize yourself with what kind of questions you can ask here and what makes a good question. Have you done any research? What have you tried? There are platform differences between Android and iOS when it comes to the status bar. (Note: This is not a coding service.)

You can also see this case: decorView.systemUiVisibility deprecated. How to replace it correctly?.

For Android, you can use the following code.
Add this to AppShell.xaml.cs:
#if  ANDROID
using Android.Views;
#endif

namespace MauiApp5
{
    public partial class AppShell : Shell
    {
        public AppShell()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
#if ANDROID
            Platform.CurrentActivity.Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)
                    (SystemUiFlags.ImmersiveSticky | SystemUiFlags.HideNavigation |
                     SystemUiFlags.Fullscreen | SystemUiFlags.Immersive);
#endif
        }
    }
}

For specific pages, add this:
<ContentPage .....
             x:Class="MauiApp5.NewPage1"
             Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"
             Title="NewPage1"
             BackgroundImageSource="ku.png">

       .......

</ContentPage>

Here is the effect.
